# Get All Computers LastLogon from All Computers in a Forest

Tags: vbscript, dns, ads

There is a forest, and I need to compile a list of inactive users / computers across the entire enterprise. Since the enterprise has DCs all over the world, there are many DCs. Do I need to query each DC, pull the accounts in existence along with lastlogon attribute, and then run the resulting file through a quicksort keeping only the lowest values for each unique account? Or, can I query a central location to determine inactivity?

I read that LastLogon is not replicated, and this is why I am asking. I cannot use lastLogonTimeStamp as it is being run against a W2K system.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the lastLogonTimeStamp attribute instead, which does get replicated. Using this attribute over a forest is only accurate when the value is more than 14 days old.

Comment: My mistake -- this is being run on a W2K system.